# Python parse google using proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, urllib

I wrote code to parse the result of google using proxies.I use Python3 
but got error or 503 Service Unavailable or 403 Forbitten or no connection.

What am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
header = "Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101"
candidate_proxies = ['http://54.183.219.170:80']
for proxy in candidate_proxies:
    print("Trying HTTP proxy %s" % proxy)
    try:
        proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http' : proxy})
        request = urllib.request.Request(url)
        request.add_header("User-Agent", header)
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        html = response.read()
        print("Got URL using proxy %s" % proxy)
        return html
        #result = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com", proxies={'http': proxy})
        break
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print("Error accessing:", url)
        if e.code == 503 and 'CaptchaRedirect' in e.read():
            print("Google is requiring a Captcha. For more information see: 'https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640'")
        print("Trying next proxy in 5 seconds")
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error accessing:", url)
        print(e)
        return None
return None
```

Question:

Why is google detecting my Proxy and how to do it correctly?

Comment: apparently, 54.183.219.170 is not your own server but an open public proxy found on the INTERNET, then what do you expect?

Comment: I tried the https://github.com/constverum/ProxyBroker to provide me proxies, but I get the same problem. So what´s the different between these "Free" proxies and someone I buy from proxyhub or so one ?

Comment: your code works for me with: url = "*http*s://google.com", so I get a valid response..

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a service like Proxicity.io (https://www.proxicity.io). You can search proxies that support Google, and you get a new verified proxy on each API request. You can use the service for free too! One of the features of the service is to check the proxy against common hosts (Google, Amazon, Craigslist, etc) and being able to query against them with the `supportedWebsites` field.

You can easily get a new, verified and tested proxy with the following:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.proxicity.io/v2/<OPTIONAL-API-KEY>/proxy')
proxy = response.json()['curl']  # curl returns protocol://ip:port format
```

*FULL DISCLOSURE: I am the lead developer on this project. Developed it for use by other developers. Don't want to get in trouble by StackOverflow, again, for sharing this service.*

Comment: How much requests is your tool working for free ? I can´t find a describtion about the limitations for free use ?

Comment: @SeeuD1 thanks for calling that out! We will get this info added for you as soon as possible! For the free, no API Key requests, you will receive 50 requests per day. I have been working on adding some promotional codes for StackOverflow users for the paid keys though! Once I get those up, I will be sure to add them here for you and others to use!

Comment: Ah yeah I find it out manually by testing your API =p , but I don´t get any proxy which is usable with google. It´s a nice API but I thought an Request for a specific website would help a lot and get down your traffic.

Answer (score -2):

You need dedicated proxies for this to work. You can find reliable providers with minimal effort.

Then you cycle through the proxies.

```
from itertools import cycle
```